# Delete orphans in Servicestack ORMLite with junction/join table

Tags: ormlite-servicestack

I've got a three table keyword structure

Team <- TeamKeyword -> Keyword

where the middle table is the junction table (join table).

I'd like to remove possible orphans from Keyword (not in use in TeamKeyword).

My first try was something intuitive like this:

```cs
var orphans = db.From<Keyword>().LeftJoin<TeamKeyword>().Where<TeamKeyword>(tk => tk == null);
db.Delete(orphans);
```

That created this SQL that doesn't work (in Sqlite):

```sql
DELETE FROM "Keyword" WHERE "Keyword"."Id" IN (SELECT "Keyword"."Id" 
FROM "Keyword" LEFT JOIN "TeamKeyword" ON
("Keyword"."Id" = "TeamKeyword"."KeywordId")
WHERE ('{}' is null))
```

I know it can be done in hand written SQL like this:

```sql
DELETE FROM Keyword
WHERE Id IN (
  SELECT k.Id
  FROM Keyword k
  LEFT JOIN TeamKeyword tk on tk.KeywordId = k.Id
  WHERE tk.Id IS NULL
)
```

So I got it working by using a table alias (needed to reference the table) and some raw SQL, but is there an easier way? It's quite a common use-case.

```cs
var orphans = db.From<Keyword>().LeftJoin<TeamKeyword>((k,tk)=>tk.KeywordId==k.Id, db.TableAlias("tk")).Where("tk.Id IS NULL");
db.Delete(orphans);
```

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question again, because I found a way. Just make the *TeamKeyword's* `Id` an `int?` (didn't think that could work, since it's the primary key, but in reality the primary key in DB will still be NOT NULL).

Then this works (creates the SQL I was looking for):

```sql
var orphans = db.From<Keyword>().LeftJoin<TeamKeyword>().Where<TeamKeyword>(k => k.Id==null);
db.Delete(orphans);
```